# Product Attribute Not creating

Tags: magento-1.9

I create Table and Product Attribute but Table is created but Product Attribute is not creating

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$sql=<<<SQLTEXT
create table tablename(tablename_id int not null auto_increment, fname ,primary key(tablename_id));

SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);
//demo 
//Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setId(null);
//demo 
$installer->endSetup();
```

**`attribute script`**

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();


$this->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'preorder', array(
        'group'             => 'General',
        'type'              => 'int',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'Is it Preorder product',
        'input'             => 'boolean',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => '',
        'is_global', Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => true,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => false,
        'default'           => '0',
        'searchable'        => false,
        'filterable'        => false,
        'comparable'        => false,
        'visible_on_front'  => false,
        'unique'            => false,
        'apply_to'          => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable',
        'is_configurable'   => false,
        'used_in_product_listing', '1'
    ));

$this->endSetup();
```

I think Name of the file name is wrong some one will guide me What problem it's

[image]

Comment: If you have already run the first file which is `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`  then the second file should be `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php` which is an upgrade file. And change the config version in config.xml too.

Comment: I install moudle with this file

Comment: Yes..so the second file would be `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php` which will upgrade the module. And change the config.xml version also to 0.1.1 and then refresh the page.

Comment: I got this error after change this Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

you are upgrading the install file so you should structure the name of file as mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php

Please try again with above, i think codes are ready to deploy.
Let me know further progress.